# no Error Messages in imported python classes

Tags: python

i have a couple of python classes, which i import and use in my main program.

```
## path to classes
sys.path.append(basePath + "classes")

## import some classes
import mainmod

mainModHandler = mainmod.Mainmod()
```

I have no problem, working with them, but i wonder, if i have a error in my imported class, i do not get an error message from Python, that only works in my main.py

For example:

```
class Mainmod(object):
'''
this class provides some helper methods
'''
def __init__(self, *args):
    provokeAnError{} # should provoke an error message?
```

My python prgramm (linux commandline) does finish but not with an error message. It just stays silent. I of course use try, excepts mostly, but sometimes little errors are unavoidable.

Where or how can i tell python, to give me an error message in my imported classes?

thanks for any help!
Maurice

Comment: Care to show some real code? `provokeAnError{}` is not syntactically correct `python`Thanks

Comment: I get a syntax error from the import on my machine.

Comment: Wooble, thanks for your comment. Strange, why do i not get a syntax error? Of course its not syntactically correct, cause to _provoke_ the syntax error.

Comment: This is a syntax error for me. Are you sure you're not importing from a different mainmod file? Try removing any .pyc files as well, in case an old version of the code is being used.

Comment: Mark, i am 100% sure, that i am working with the correct files. Every changes i made do affect correctly, so there can be no doubt. But i think, i've now no the reason for this problem. This only happens for classes, i do import at runtime with: __import__(module)

Comment: You can check where a module is imported from through its `__file__` attribute.  For example, you can check `mainmod.__file__` to verify that's it is being imported from the expected location.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is importing your module then you wouldn't get an error since that error would only happen when instantiating the class.  It's unclear from your question if the code that you give as an example is the exact code you expect to produce the error.

If that isn't it, provide more context, maybe links to full files.